# IE Rendering Issues in WPF / WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I am using a WinForms Browser control in a WPF application. I have set the registry to use IE 11 using 11001 and 11000.

I have loaded my app on multiple machines and I am seeing strange rendering issues between them. I load the same page on a Surface Pro 3, a few different laptops and compare them. Some render fine, with clean HTML and rounded corner CSS. On some machines, the corners are square, the pages look horrible. Broken CSS, bad javascript, etc.

I have loaded the app using a few of those online "browser information checking" tools and they all match, same engine is used, IE 11. No JavaScript Errors, I've cleared the cache, reset the IE settings manually.

Any ideas why I am setting the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, some machines have DPI scaling and this was impacting the control. Apparently the control doesn't perform DPI scaling well without helpers.

I did not have helpers so the solution was to disable the scaling in the AssemblyInfo.cs. See code below.

[assembly: DisableDpiAwareness]

Impacts: Text will be fuzzy if it is scaled now, as the display is not handling the DPI changes. But this allows the pages to render correctly.